# Spring Security doesnt recognize its own encryption

Tags: hibernate, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, bcrypt

I have problem with Spring Security and encrypting password in **MsSQL**. In my REST app I use `Spring 4`, `Hibernate` and `Spring Data JPA`. I'm trying to implement encryption of the password with `Bcrypt`, however I only get

```
WARN 4780 --- [io-8080-exec-61] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder
:Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

when trying to login with correct credentials. And then access is obviously denied.

What I tried or what I know:

1. Password in MS SQL is stored correctly, as a Bcrypt encrypted string
2. Place for password in DB is long enough (64 chars)
3. Adding  `auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)` to AuthenticationManagerBuilder didnt change anything.
4. When asking DB for password it returns what is stored - Brypt encoded password.

The whole thing is kinda strange since I'm use same instance of PasswordEncoder to encode everything. And then it doesnt recognize its own encryption. What I have :

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userAuthService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/home", "/").permitAll()  
                        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/addGame").hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);

    }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }

        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userAuthService);
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
            return authProvider;
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

}
```

UserDetailsService:

```
@Service 
public class UserAuthService implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    UserDatabaseService userDatabaseService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserDto user = userDatabaseService.getUserByUsername(username);
        if ( user == null ){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        } else{
            return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
        }

    }

}
```

UserDatabaseService (implemented with Spring Data):

```
@Service
public class UserDatabaseService {

    @Autowired
    UserDatabaseRepository userDatabaseRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserToUserDtoConverter userToUserDtoConverter;

    @Autowired
    UserDtoToUserEntityConverter userDtoToUserEntityConverter;

    @Autowired 
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserDto getUserByUsername(String username){
        return userToUserDtoConverter.convert( userDatabaseRepository.findByUsername(username) );
    }

    public boolean saveUser(UserDto user){
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        if ( userDatabaseRepository.save( userDtoToUserEntityConverter.convert(user) ) != null ){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

To be honest I dont really know whats wrong. I've been following those two tutorials:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt

All help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: converters used to convert DTO classes to Entity ( and vice versa )

```
@Service 
public class UserDtoToUserEntityConverter {
    public UserEntity convert(UserDto user){
        return new UserEntity(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword() , user.getEmail() );
    }

    public Collection<UserEntity> convertAll(Collection<UserDto> fElements){
        Collection<UserEntity> convertedElement =
                fElements.stream()
                        .map(element -> convert(element))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return convertedElement;
    }

}

@Service 
public class UserToUserDtoConverter implements UserDtoConverter {

    @Override
    public UserDto convert(UserEntity from) {
        return new BaseUserDto( from.getFirstName(), from.getLastName(), 
                                from.getUsername(), from.getPassword(),
                                from.getEmail() );
    }

}
```

MyUserPrincipal:

```
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails{
    private UserDto user;

    public MyUserPrincipal(UserDto user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }



}
```

Comment: @dur I've edited the original question, if you could take a look I would be really grateful. Those converters dont do much thou.

Comment: Yep I've tried it - it returns properly encoded password. However there's something wrong not only with encoding - without it I also cant log in. Does Spring Data hate Hibernate or something...?

Comment: MyUserPrincipal is class implementing "UserDetails" interface from Spring Security. I've added code to the question, it also doesnt really do much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering what was the problem - database returned password and blank spaces at the end of it... Thats why it could never authenticate, password provided was always "different" from the one stored in db... God damn.